# Can I batchly set tags in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Suppose I have hundreds lines of items:

```
**** aa
**** bb
......
**** cc
```

I try to multiply set tags. I tried to mark them, and use `C-c C-q`, but it didn't works

Comment: Also have a look at [Tag Inheritance](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-inheritance.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As org files are plain text files, we can add tags using a simple approach: `query-replace-regexp`.

1. Go to the beginning of the buffer.
2. Do `M-x query-replace-regexp` or use the default binding `C-M-%`.
3. Enter regexp to match the org headings: `^\*+\s-+.*`
4. To add a tag, you basically append the heading with a space, a `:` and the tag.
   So the replacement text would be `\& :MYTAG`. *Here `\&` represents whatever text was matched in the "search" step above.*
5. Now you can review and hit yes only where you want the tag to be appended, or just hit `!` if you want to append tags to all the org headings in the buffer.

---

Here's an example org buffer:

```
* abc
** def
*** ghi
* jkl
** mno
```

By implementing the above steps and hit `!` in that last step, that would get converted to:

```
* abc :MYTAG
** def :MYTAG
*** ghi :MYTAG
* jkl :MYTAG
** mno :MYTAG
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. By the way, why do you use `-+` in regular expression. It is my first time to see it

Comment: @yuxuan `\s-` is regexp for whitespace. Check out the `\scode` section [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html).

Answer (score 8):

If the headlines you want to change tags for are all located in a contiguous region you can highlight them all, and then use the `org-change-tag-in-region` command.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, the other feels like a workaround. see also: http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/tag-multiple-headlines-at-once-in-org-mode/

Answer (score 6):

`org-agenda` supports many [bulk actions](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html).  Do an `org-agenda` search (`C-c a`) that matches the entries you're interested in.  In the agenda view use `m` to mark them (or `*` to mark everything) and the `B` to select a bulk action.  The `+` action will add a tag to each entry.